# Как найти php.ini который читает Docker?

Tags: php, docker

При попытке связаться с mysql бд с помощью

`$this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->password, $opt);`

Происходит ошибка Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver. В phpInfo стоит

```
PDO drivers         sqlite
```

Как я понял, нужно прописать расширение mysql в файле php.ini, но я никак не могу его найти. phpInfo выглядит так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как найти php.ini?
P.S. Докер на Windows

Comment: там же, в выводе функции phpinfo. например (первая же картинка, найденная по запросу «phpinfo»): [шестой пункт  — «loaded configuration file»](https://camo.qiitausercontent.com/01b9ec2600986d1342fbca1d725f41205817c588/68747470733a2f2f71696974612d696d6167652d73746f72652e73332e61702d6e6f727468656173742d312e616d617a6f6e6177732e636f6d2f302f3338383532352f35353538636436632d343463322d643330362d303562362d3735306335323166386430652e706e67). p.s. это путь внутри **файловой системы контейнера**, а не файловой системы вашего компьютера.

Answer (score 1):

А где и как вы делаете? Вообще php.ini лежит в папке своей версии А где и как вы делаете? Вообще php.ini лежит в папке своей версии, например в ubuntu это /etc или /var/shared не помню точно, кажись в etc... В той же Ubuntu версию можно узнать 'php -v'

Но подозреваю, что вы просто не в ту папку его распаковали, или что-то такое, на сколько я понимаю докеру не нужно указывать эту информацию

Comment: У меня докер стоит на Windows, в этом и проблема как я понимаю. На скринах что я нашел в интернете, у всех путь C/Windows/..., а у меня какой-то usr, который непонятно где находится. Весь диск C пересмотрел,безрезультатно

Comment: А зачем эти извращения, почему бы не развернуть виртуалку на локалке и работать в более правильной среде!?

Comment: Или не воспользоваться https://aws.amazon.com/ru/ и играться на живую целый год бесплатно и зачем вам докер?)) Используйте образы, я думаю вам этого за глаза! Готовый стек можно найти под любые пожелания, хоть с докером, хоть без, также из него быстро можно развернуть готовый и настроенный сервак, или вам эту сборку нужно делать каждый раз разную и часто разворачивать на разных машинах?

Comment: Задали развернуть докер на Windows, вот и разбираюсь. А так да, Ваши варианты намного лучше

Comment: Я бы конечно выбрал azure, но для России халява похожие закончилась...

Comment: Так а задачи какие докер должен выполнять? Так-то у докера есть декстоп версия под винду если что )

Comment: Ну так у меня и стоит версия под винду. Задачи максимально примитивные - написать запросы к бд из пхп и что бы все это было под докером(надеюсь правильно обьяснил)

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows ну ему нужно при сборке контейнера указать какая версия будет использоваться при развертывании, а самому докеру php не нужен... Смысл докера как composer, а на месте он из репозитория скачает все зависимости

Comment: https://youtu.be/EbEZgdTOHzE